# Postgres SQLAlchemy: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'ForeignKey'

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I am using postgres database and sqlalchemy in my python code,
I created schemas and models and I want to use ForeignKey, but I got this error message:

```
Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'ForeignKey'
```

my code:

```
class table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    first_id = Column(
        Integer, unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True
    )


class table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    second_id = Column(
        Integer,
        nullable=False,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    second = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, ForeignKey=('table1.first_id'))
```

Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `ForeignKey` from `sqlalchemy` and create it as positional argument to `Column`.

```py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey

class table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    first_id = Column(
        Integer, unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True
    )


class table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    second_id = Column(
        Integer,
        nullable=False,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    second = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table1.first_id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
```

### Documentation

[ForeignKey](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey)

[Column params](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=column#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.*args)

Comment: I have imported it, and it is defined in Column

Comment: You are using the keyword argument `"ForeignKey"` to `Column` instead of declaring an instance of `ForeignKey`.  Please look at the `second = Column...` line in my answer.